# Grafana and Elasticsearch: How to perform a simple query

Tags: elasticsearch, grafana

Using **Grafana** 7.2 and Elasticsearch 7.5.1.

I am storing in **Elasticsearch** a structure that, among other things, indexes an `executionTime` field in milliseconds:

[image: example of elasticsearch structure]

Using Grafana, how do I filter by that field? So I can get only values with `executionTime < 150`, for example.

Something like this is not working:

[image: Using query field in Grafana]

Something like this is not working either:

[image: Using filter field in Grafana]

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found!

As setted in [official Grafana documentation](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/datasources/elasticsearch/), Lucene queries can be used in the query field.